# how get hash info from a torrent file using php?

Tags: parsing, hash, torrent, info

Is any way to find hash info from a torrent file?
I want to put a form that upload a torrent file, then when it upload, get just hash info from that torrent file,

is it possible using PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

It's certainly possible. You will need [a library](https://packagist.org/search/?q=bencode) to deserialize the data from the [bencode format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) torrent files are using, and then access `info.pieces`